# MySQL select user motto

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck on this problem and I have been trying to solve for like 2 hours.

I have a `posts` table which contains all posts. Each post has a column called `ownerid` which keeps the id of the owner of this post. And it also contains a column called `groupid`.

What I want to have is to select all posts with a specific `groupid` (*eg. 2)*
and the `motto` of the user which is in `users` table.

So something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE groupid = 2

SELECT motto FROM users WHERE userid = $row['ownerid']
```

But both queries in one line, because I'm using while loop to fetch rows.

```
$stmt->bind_result($postid, $motto, $groupid, $text, $postdate);
```

Comment: Could you show expected output of the query?

Comment: @jussius I suppose that he wants all the content of the posts table's rows for a selected groupid and (joined with) the user motto, relative to the user owner of each post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand correctly your question, you should try

```
SELECT P.*, U.motto from posts P INNER JOIN users U on P.ownerid = U.userid 
WHERE P.groupid = 2;
```

Comment: @I'm glad for you! If the answer is correct, please accept it! bye!

Answer (score 1):

So you should obtail all the columns from both the tables related by group id and group id =2

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM posts as a
INNER JOIN user as b on a.groupid = b.groupid
WHERE a.groupid = 2
```